# How to show ant design time picker future time

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd, react-typescript

I'm using ant design date time picker, I'm disabling the past date and  before the current time, but I have some conflict on the picker, when I click  the future date that time always disable before the current time, anyone knows some solution for the issue

**[here the stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x3yr71)**

**Here my code**

```
    //date disable
        disabledDate(current: any) {
            // Can not select days before today and today
            //return current && current < moment().endOf('day');
            return current && current < moment().startOf("day")
        }

        //time disable
        getDisabledHours() {
            var hours = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < moment().hour(); i++) {
                hours.push(i);
            }
            return hours;
        }

        //time disable
        getDisabledMinutes = (selectedHour: any) => {
            var minutes = [];
            if (selectedHour === moment().hour()) {
                for (var i = 0; i < moment().minute(); i++) {
                    minutes.push(i);
                }
            }
            return minutes;
        }
```

```
     <DatePicker
       name="Date" disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
       onChange={this.onChangeDate}
       style={{width: "100%"}}
       showTime={{ disabledMinutes: this.getDisabledMinutes, 
       disabledHours: this.getDisabledHours}}
      />
```

Comment: You just want the user to select the date/time of present/future, and disable all the past dates, is that it?

Comment: @SirajAlam Hello there, yes, that is  a my conflict, i update my conflict in using stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x3yr71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem that I found in your code is, while disabling the hours, you're not taking selected date into consideration.

Just add a condition, that disables logic will run only for the current date, and not for the future dates.
For that condition, you can compare your currently selected date from the state.

```
<DatePicker
   name="Date" disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
   onChange={date => this.setSatate({date})}
   style={{width: "100%"}}
   value={moment(this.state.date)}
   showTime={{ 
      disabledMinutes: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledMinutes, 
      disabledHours: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledHours
   }}
  />
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rtsqmw

> Note: onChange only triggers when you click `OK` button in the picker, and after selecting a date, when you select the time, then the disable issue will disappear. I not aware of ant design APIs much, but your issue is fixed, all you have to do is update the state of the selected date on clicking on the date and not `OK` button

Comment: Hello, I added your code but not working, if you have a time, can you please update using my  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x3yr71

Comment: @core114, I have added stackblitz link, please check.

Comment: Hi, Thank for your valuable time and solution